# New iOS project, free hosted repository: Xcode 4 or Xcode 3.2?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, repository, xcode3.2, xcode3to4

I wonder whether I should start development of a new iOS project in Xcode 4 or 3.2 - on one hand, I know 3.2 (a little), there is lots of info about it out there, and it's stable and proven. On the other hand, Xcode 4 brings some improvements as well. Are the newer previews of Xcode 4 ready for prime time, or are they still too buggy?

I'm especially interested in issues with (and recommendations of) externally hosted repositories, as I was not very happy with how Xcode 3.2 played with the Subversion repository in my last project.

Which one to choose, and which (preferably free and externally hosted) repository to match?

Comment: I swear I saw the same question just last week...

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. Searching for Xcode 4, "Xcode 4" and +Xcode +4 either turned up too much noise, or came up empty. I only thought of trying Xcode4 after posting my question.

Comment: There, I edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today (3rd Feb 2011) Apple released the GM-Seed of xcode4. It's now ready for usage and you can compile your apps and release to the app-store. So if you are new with xcode, I would suggest using xcode4.

Why?

1. The new compiler has a lot of optimizations done. The compiler (as far as I can see the results) generates faster code. It's big fun!
2. The new Userinterface is more reliable. It makes your development a lot faster!

   2a. Interface builder is now integrated. You can "drag and drop" your userinterface Item using the "ctrl"-key into your code and xcode creates the source for you! This accelerates creation of userinterfaces a lot!
3. git support has been added to sourcecontrol, which makes development in teams easier
4. The new LLVM compiler shows errors immediately while coding. And it displays errors, which xcode3 never mentioned

In xcode4 Apple changed a lot! So if you start with xcode3, you will have a new learning curve with xcode 4. For newbs I suggest: Download the xcode4 goldmaster and get startet with xcode4!

Comment: Now that the final is out, I think for a new project the choice is obvious: Xcode 4 is the first version of the future of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I second JackPearse's endorsement of Xcode 4, with one caveat. Been using Xcode 4 for a couple of days and am really starting to like it. Particularly like the way it shows the changes in each file as you commit. Unfortunately, when you delete a file, it forgets that it will need to be deleted in the repository as well. But the big **BUT** right now is that Xcode 4 will immediately crash the moment you try to do any Core Data modeling. See also [XCode 4 Data Model Versioning bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331268/xcode-4-data-model-versioning-bug) here on Stack Overflow. So, if you plan to use Core Data, you'll need to keep Xcode 3 around as well until they fix this.