# Xcode 4 Data Model Versioning bug?

Tags: core-data, xcode4

Installed Xcode 4 and it all seems fine... except, when I try to add versioning to a Core Data model. In the instructions it says I should select the data model in the navigator and then "Choose Editor > Convert to Versioned Model." Well, the "Editor" menu does not have an item "Convert to Versioned Model"!!! Skipping this step crashes Xcode 4. Also, I can't believe that there is no support for Xcode 4 now that it is a pay product!

Answer (score 2):

There are currently several issues with the core data model editor in Xcode 4.  I highly recommend installing Xcode 3 next to Xcode 4 and doing all of your model work in Xcode 3 until these issues are addressed.

I also recommend filing a [feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) so that you can add your voice to this issue.

Comment: It's definitely an Xcode 4 bug, see also http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2788548&tstart=105. As soon as I do anything Core Data related, my two-day old Xcode 4 installation hangs until I force it to quit. The shape of the report suggests an endless loop. Shame, I was just starting to make friends with 4. Anyway, off to install 3.

Comment: Just downloaded 4.0.2 Build 4A2002a and still the same issue! I've filed a bug report (no.9290774) -- I doubt it's the only one on this issue but I was a bit angry. I don't understand how they can release a new version without fixing this -- it's like painting a house but not fixing the leak in the roof.

Comment: Does anyone know if they have fixed this issue yet?

Comment: It hasn't been resolved in Xcode 4.1 as far as I can see. I'm selecting Editor->Add Model Version, and it crashes just after saving the versioned data model.

Answer (score 2):

First select your xcdatamodeld file and go to the Editor Menu and select the Add Model Version option.
After you create your new version select again the xcdatamodeld file and be sure you have the Utilities sidebar shown and select the first icon, the File Inspector one. You will have a Versioned Data Model option.

Hope that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with xcode 4.5. And after some time I have resolved it:

1. Move my test.xcdatamodel file to the root in the project navigator.
2. Highlight file in a new location and select Editor -> Add Model Version...

And xcode automatically creates *.xcdatamodeld with two files : 'test 2.xcdatamodel' and 'test.xcdatamodel'. And 'test 2.xcdatamodel' is marked as current version.