# How to turn datamodel into a versioned datamodel in Xcode4?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, core-data, xcode4, database-versioning

I remember that in Xcode 3.x you could simply Add Model Version and Xcode would convert your datamodel into a versioned datamodel. For some reason when I try doing so following the same steps in Xcode4, it crashes the environment and doesn't make any of the desired changes.

Does anyone know the right steps on versioning and migrating your datamodel in Xcode4?

I just found this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331268/xcode-4-data-model-versioning-bug) and commented on it. I believe it's the same bug and they haven't fixed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Editor > Convert to Versioned Model to convert a data model to a versioned data model.

Comment: The editor menu in Xcode4 doesn't have Convert to Versioned Model.

Comment: You're right. They must have removed that menu item in one of the Xcode 4 previews. Choosing Editor > Add Model Version is the way to convert a data model to a versioned data model. Doing the conversion crashes Xcode for me, but it does create the versioned data model. Add the versioned data model to your project.

Comment: With me, whenever I Add Model Version it simply crashes Xcode without creating the versioned data model, so I guess I'm screwed until they fix the bug right?

Comment: If your data model isn't too big, your best option would be to add a new data model to your project and use that model. When you create a new data model in Xcode 4, the newly created model is a versioned data model.

Comment: If I do it this way, won't the data not be migrated though?

Comment: You would have to recreate the entities. That's why I prefaced my previous comment with "If your data model isn't too big". Your other alternative is to use Xcode 3.2 to convert the data model to a versioned data model.